# Recursive Depth First Search Algorithm - what is the general case/base case/initial situation?

Tags: java, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

Per my reasoning, the base case is when all nodes on the graph have been visited.

The general case is when all adjacent edges are labeled.

The initial situation is when a single node is picked as the starting point.

Is this correct? The possible answers are the following:

A. Have "discovered" an unvisited node.
B. All adjacent edges are labeled.
C. All edges on the graph have been visited.
D. All nodes on the graph have been visited.
E. A single node is picked as the starting point.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you checked a textbook which explains this in detail?

Comment: [Introduction to Algorithms](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844)

Answer (score 0):

```
Depth-First-Search-Kickoff( Maze m )
    Depth-First-Search( m.StartCell )
End procedure

Depth-First-Search( MazeCell c )
    If c is the goal
        Exit
    Else
        Mark c "Visit In Progress"
        Foreach neighbor n of c
            If n "Unvisited"
                Depth-First-Search( n )
        Mark c "Visited"
End procedure
```

http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse326/03su/homework/hw3/dfs.html
You need to use memoization to mark the nodes.

If you were not using recursion you could implement dfs using a queue and check to see if the queue is empty.

Comment: For BFS we can use Recurssion or explicit stack not the Queue, Queue should be used in the case of BFS.